# Pandas qcut binning returning only one group

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am working with pandas pcut and somethimes (when a lot of data are equal to the min) it returns either an error:

```
Bin edges must be unique
```

Or I have to drop the non-unique bins that I get, but then all my data are in one bin.

For example:
dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
nbins = 2
pd.qcut([0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3], nbins)
```

I want then to have the ones above or below the median (here 0).
Then I am expecting to get:

```
[grp1, grp1, grp1, grp1, grp1, grp2, grp2, grp2]
```

But what are get are either:

```
pd.qcut([0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3], 2)
out >>> ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([ 0.,  0.,  3.]).
```

If I drop non-unique bins:

```
pd.qcut([0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3], 2, duplicates='drop')
out >>> [(-0.001, 3.0], (-0.001, 3.0], (-0.001, 3.0], (-0.001, 3.0], (-0.001, 3.0], (-0.001, 3.0], (-0.001, 3.0], (-0.001, 3.0]]
Categories (1, interval[float64]): [(-0.001, 3.0]]
```

And everything is in only one category.

I don't want to have necessarily +/- median, this is just an example when data are clustered around the min.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very ugly way to solve it...:

```
try: 
    pd.qcut(data, n_bins)
except ValueError:
    pd.qcut(data, n_bins+1, duplicates = 'drop')
```